# Find $P(X\leq 0.5| Y= 0.4)$ if $f(x, y)=(x+y) I_{(0,1)}(x) I_{(0,1)}(y)$

Tags: probability

Find $P(X\leq 0.5| Y= 0.4)$

if $f(x, y)=(x+y) I_{(0,1)}(x) I_{(0,1)}(y)$

I calculate $f_y(y)=\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1} x+y \cdot dx=y+\frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
$

then $f_{x|y}(x|y)=\frac{x+y}{y+\frac{1}{2}} $

But im stuck here i dont know what integral i have to calculate

I have to do

$ \int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{x+0.4}{0.4+\frac{1}{2}} \,dx $ ?

Comment: Right. Let $y= 0.4$ in your $f_{x|y}$, then take the  integral on $x\in (-\infty,0.5]$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X\leq 0.5\mid Y=0.4)~ &=~ \int_{-\infty}^{0.5} f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid 0.4)\,\mathrm d x\\[2ex] &= ~\int_{0}^{0.5} \frac{x+0.4}{0.4+0.5} \,\mathrm dx \end{align}$$

---

Indeed all your prior calculations were correct, save that you neglected to indicate the supports for the functions.  Don't forget those or marks may be deducted in your exams.

Comment: Thank you! I miss to indicate the supports here :D just one question what if i want to calculate $P(X=0.6| Y=0.4)$ i just to to replace in $f_{x|y}(x|y)=\frac{x+y}{y+\frac{1}{2}}$ ? because im getting a probability of $1.11...$ and i think that is not correct

Comment: The only thing you replace is the integration's domain. @GustavoOrtega $$\displaystyle\int_0^{0.6}\dfrac{x+0.4}{0.4+1/2}\,\mathrm dx=\tfrac 1 9 \big[5x^2+4x\big]_{x=0}^{x=0.6}$$